# Python 2.7, ValueError when dealing with HTMLParser

Tags: python, html-parsing

First time working with the HTMLParser module. Trying to use standard string formatting on the ouput, but it's giving me an error. The following code:

```
import urllib2
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class LinksParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self, url):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        req = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        self.feed(req.read())

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag != 'a': return
        for name, value in attrs:
        print("Found Link --> {]".format(value))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    LinksParser("http://www.facebook.com"
```

Produces the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\workspace\test\src\test.py", line 15, in handle_starttag  
print("Found Link --> {]".format(value))  
ValueError: unmatched '{' in format
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print("Found Link --> {]".format(value))
```

Should instead be:

```
print("Found Link --> {}".format(value))
```

You used a square bracket instead of a brace.

Comment: Wow, I feel silly. Good eye catching that. Lol, perhaps I should increase the font size of my editor. :) Working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

This format string looks broken: `print("Found Link --> {]".format(value))`. You need to change this to `print("Found Link --> {key}".format(key = value))`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems

- the print statement in `handle_starttag` should be indented
- in the last line you're missing the closing parenthesis
- in the print statement in `handle_starttag` you should use `{0}` instead of `{]`